# How to change the tmp directory used by a specific service user?

Tags: environment-variables, tmp

I want to change the temporary directory used by a specific user (`jenkins` in my case).

The problem is that this needs to be in effect for any process running as Jenkins user and changing it in `.profile` is not supposed to work because these are non-interactive logins.

Answer (score 3):

On most systems, you can set environment variables in the file `~/.pam_environment` and they will apply to all login methods, even those that don't start a login shell and so don't load `.profile`. This file is read by the PAM module `pam_env`, i.e. the PAM configuration file `/etc/pam.conf` or `/etc/pam.d/XXX` for the service that logs the user in should mention the `pam_env` module.

The syntax of `~/.pam_environment` is one `VARIABLE=VALUE` per line. You can't have any shell syntax such as quoting or references to other variables. In your case you would put a line like

```
TMPDIR=/somewhere/tmp-for-builds
```